# AutoIt - Detect System Shutdown/Reboot

Tags: system, autoit, shutdown, reboot

I want to make AutoIt display a msgbox when system is about to shutdown or reboot.
I tried this one:

```
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$hGUI = GuiCreate("") ; Create a GUI and don't show it
GuiRegisterMsg($WM_ENDSESSION, "WM_ENDSESSION")

; Do stuff here...
While 1 ; Loop does nothing
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func WM_ENDSESSION($hWnd, $Msg, $wParam, $lParam)
    MsgBox(0,"SystemShutdown", @HOUR & ":" & @MIN & ":" & @SEC & @TAB & "WM_ENDSESSION: " & $hWnd & ", " & $Msg & ", " & $wParam & ", " & $lParam & @CRLF)
EndFunc
```

But it won't work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    #include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstants.au3>
#include <date.au3>
;~ #define PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND           0x0000
;~ #define PBT_APMQUERYSTANDBY           0x0001
;~ #define PBT_APMQUERYSUSPENDFAILED     0x0002
;~ #define PBT_APMQUERYSTANDBYFAILED     0x0003
;~ #define PBT_APMSUSPEND                0x0004
;~ #define PBT_APMSTANDBY                0x0005
;~ #define PBT_APMRESUMECRITICAL         0x0006
;~ #define PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND      0x0007
;~ #define PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY      0x0008
;~ #define PBTF_APMRESUMEFROMFAILURE     0x00000001
;~ #define PBT_APMBATTERYLOW             0x0009
;~ #define PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE  0x000A
;~ #define PBT_APMOEMEVENT               0x000B
;~ #define PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC        0x0012
Global $PBT_APMSUSPEND = 0x0004
Global $PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND = 0x0007
Global $PBT_APMSTANDBY = 0x0005
Global $PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY = 0x0008

$hGUI = GUICreate("Test", 100, 100, 1, 1)
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_POWERBROADCAST, "Standby")
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_QUERYENDSESSION, "_Shutdown")
;~ GUISetState()
While 1
    Sleep(10)
;~ $GUIMsg = GUIGetMsg()
;~   Switch $GUIMsg
;~       Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
;~           ExitLoop
;~   EndSwitch
WEnd
;
Exit
;
Func Standby($hWnd, $Msg, $wParam, $lParam)
    ConsoleWrite(_NowTime() & ": " & $wParam & @LF)
    Select
        Case $wParam = $PBT_APMSUSPEND
            ConsoleWrite(" You going into Suspend." & @LF)
        Case $wParam = $PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND
            ConsoleWrite(" You just woke up from Suspend." & @LF)
        Case $wParam = $PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY
            ConsoleWrite(" You are going into Standby." & @LF)
        Case $wParam = $PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY
            ConsoleWrite(" You just woke up from Standby." & @LF)
            ;MsgBox(0,"Hello Back", " You just woke up from Standby")
        Case Else
    EndSelect
EndFunc   ;==>Standby

Func _Shutdown()
    MsgBox(16, 'SHUTDOWN', ' oh oh shutting down ... ')
EndFunc   ;==>_Shutdown
```